# need help regarding map activity-Android

Tags: android

*when creating a map activity ...done with api key n all*
*but getting blank graph view ...google map is not coming plz help*
*
*
*my code''*

### *

*
*.java file*
*
*
*

```
package com.example.googlemap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity

{

  @Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

  {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);





   }

   @Override

   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()

   {

    return false;

   }

}
```

### -

manifest..file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.googlemap"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <activity android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"

              android:label="@string/app_name"

              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>



   <uses-permission 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">


    </uses-permission>


  </manifest>
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

main.xml...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0sCrqI4KHZ_BsBA98HTm1iQMmkIFRjDKgIyJupg"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same keystore to sign the apk which you used while getting the apiKey?

Comment: You have to use the debug keystore to get your API key if you're going to use it for development purposes only, and a new API key, generated with your production certificate when you're about to launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your apiKey is wrong.  I took all your code and tried it quickly and it didn't work.  I changed the apiKey to my own and it showed a map just fine.

Comment: is this api is correct.. "0sCrqI4KHZ_AkkohjfKxm_ur-rCAH3o92uzzoFw"

Comment: Check here for details on debug keystore: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint